# Identifying functions writing to memory at LLVM-IR level

Tags: llvm-clang, llvm-ir

How can i retrieve pointer to a memory area that is accessed by a function call . 
I have written a Pass that can intercept function calls and detect whether it is writing to a memory on not using `Instruction::mayWriteToMemory()`. Whether a function accessing memory or not can be checked by 
`Instruction::mayReadFromMemory()` and `Instruction::mayWriteToMemory()` but how can i get staring address of those memory areas (program variables) that are being written by.

For example, for the c code

```
int main(){
char arrd[]="This is destination ";
char arrs[]="COPIED STRING";
strcpy(arrd, arrs);
printf("Final copied string : %s\n", arrd);
return 0;
}
```

I want to get the staring address and end address of memory areas (variables) being written by **strcpy** function.

The LLVM-IR code generated for this is

```
%arrd = alloca [21 x i8], align 16
%arrs = alloca [14 x i8], align 1
%0 = bitcast [21 x i8]* %arrd to i8*
call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %0, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([21 x i8]*       @main.arrd, i32 0, i32 0), i64 21, i32 16, i1 false)
%1 = bitcast [14 x i8]* %arrs to i8*
call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %1, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([14 x i8]* @main.arrs, i32 0, i32 0), i64 14, i32 1, i1 false) 
%arraydecay = getelementptr inbounds [21 x i8]* %arrd, i32 0, i32 0
%arraydecay1 = getelementptr inbounds [14 x i8]* %arrs, i32 0, i32 0
%call = call i8* @strcpy(i8* %arraydecay, i8* %arraydecay1) #1
%arraydecay2 = getelementptr inbounds [21 x i8]* %arrd, i32 0, i32 0
%call3 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([26 x i8]* @.str, i32  0, i32 0), i8* %arraydecay2) 
ret i32 0
```

Comment: I figured it out. It is not possible to do that at LLVM-IR level.